# How to Learn Typescript with Visual Studio Code + Environment setup + for beginners?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, environment

Many beginners still facing the difficulties while doing Environment setup for Learn typescript. [before step-up to Angular]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's 8 simple steps to set an Environment to learn TypeScript with Visual Studio Code.

1. Installing the TypeScript compiler by:

   ```
     npm install -g typescript
   ```
2. Install Visual Studio Code
3. Create new folder or open existing folder (empty Ex.LearnTSFolder) in - Visual Studio Code
4. Create a file - `tsconfig.json` - inside your folder(ex. LearnTSFolder)
   and put this code inside - `tsconfig.json` - file

   ```
   {
       "compilerOptions": {
           "target": "es5",
           "module": "commonjs",
           "sourceMap": true
       }
   }
   ```
5. Now Create a simple TS file `HelloWorld.ts`,  and put this code inside this ts file:

   ```
   class Startup {
       public static main(): number {
           console.log('Hello World, Wazz Up');
           return 0;
       }
   }

   Startup.main();
   ```
6. Now at Terminal run this command:

   ```
   tsc HelloWorld.ts
   ```

   ............
   so by this you can see new transpiled file - `HelloWorld.js` generate inside the our folder
7. Now Execute Run Build Task (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) from the global Terminal menu
8. **IT'S DONE NOW**..: To execute code; just run below command at Terminal:

   ```
   node HelloWorld.js
   ```

   this way we can see below message in Terminal:

   ```
   Hello World, Wazz Up
   ```

Comment: getting The term 'tsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.